# pubxml XML to change a web.config value on web deployment

Tags: visual-studio, web-config, publish, webdeploy, web-config-transform

Suppose I have a `web.config` parameter under `<appSettings><add key="myParam" value="myValue"/></appSettings>` and I want to modify the value for `myParam` depending on the publish profile I use, ie `DEVELOPMENT.pubxml` and `TEST.pubxml` for a *web site* deployment.

What is the most straightforward way to accomplish this? How do I specify in the `pubxml` which keys I want to transform, where they are, etc?

Either a direct answer or a link to a resource that answers this question would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create Web.config transform files for publish profiles as well as for build configurations. When you publish, either in Visual Studio or from the command line, Visual Studio applies both the appropriate build configuration transform and the publish profile transform.  See this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

This is one of a series of tutorials. Others in the series run through examples of creating publish profile transforms and examples of doing it from the command line.

The tutorials use a web application project. If by web site deployment you mean you're deploying a web site project, the process is basically the same as long as you have installed the latest VS update (see the first tutorial in the series for links to the VS update).

Comment: The very quick guide: creating a publish transform in VS 2013 is done by locating the profile under Properties/PublishProfiles and then select Add Config Transform in the context menu. The transform will then appear under Web.config and can be filled in. This part took me a bit to figure out, the format for the transform file is easy to google.

Comment: I meant 'creating the config transform'.

Comment: (As you said) The very cool part here is that you can have 'Release' properties defined in `Web.Release.config` and server specific in `Web.PUBXMLFILENAME.config` and they get merged based upon the configuration set for that pubxml file (you could have staging instead with a `Web.Staging.config` that is shared).